# Extract Pattern in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am extracting a pattern from the column of the dataframe. Some has the Word 'Oscar' and some has the Word 'Oscars'. How to extract in the panda dataframe . Below is the extract line code. This gives error.

```
 df['Oscar_Awards_Won']  = df['Awards'].str.extract('Won  (\d+) (Oscar[s]?)', expand=True).fillna(0)
```

I am sorry for not posting Sample data.Sample data with column Awards. I am trying to extract the no of Oscars won.

```
Awards
Won 3 Oscars. Another 234 wins & 312 nominations.
Won 7 Oscars. Another 215 wins & 169 nominations.
Won 11 Oscars. Another 174 wins & 113 nominations.
Won 4 Oscars. Another 122 wins & 213 nominations.
Won 3 Oscars. Another 92 wins & 150 nominations.
Won 1 Oscar. Another 91 wins & 95 nominations.
```

Comment: I need example data and expected output.  Read [***MCVE***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [***HowToAsk***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You are lucky your question did not get downvoted for not providing with sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what is needed?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': ['is Oscar','asd','Oscars','not an Oscars q']})

df['c'] = ['Won 3 Oscars. Another 234 wins & 312 nominations.',
'Won 7 Oscars. Another 215 wins & 169 nominations.',
'Won 11 Oscar. Another 174 wins & 113 nominations.',
'Won 4 Oscars. Another 122 wins & 213 nominations.']
```

This line:

```
df['c'].str.extract('Won (\d+) Oscar[s]?', expand=True).fillna(0)
```

Gives:

```
    0
0   3
1   7
2  11
3   4
```

Comment: It is not working for my sample data. I have posted sample data above

Comment: I need to get only the number before oscar or oscars. It comes only for oscar. The number before oscars does not come

Comment: Ah, i see. Misunderstood first. Please check the corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work because you don't need to worry the letter s anyway.

```
df['Oscar_Awards_Won']=df['Awards'].str.extract('Won (\d+) Oscar', expand=True).fillna(0)
```